# Protocol buffers with the uppercase and extension .proto.swift vs .pb.swift

Tags: ios, swift, protocol-buffers

I have a problem when I am compiling the protocol buffers un swift,
I write this protoc *.proto --swift_out="./" and works, but the problem is that my file is     `DirectionDTO.proto` and the file that this give me is `DirectionDto.proto.swift`  and when do this in the past this give me this file `DirectionDTO.pb.swift` my proto file is

```
message DirectionDTO
{
  optional double Latitude = 1;
  optional double Longitude = 2;
  optional int32 Index = 3;
  optional string Address = 4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [reading the source code](https://github.com/alexeyxo/protobuf-swift/commit/6f64fadd5dd28eceb9ddcbc91fc9a5f6b30f01d4), it looks like the Swift protobuf compiler switched from outputting `.pb.swift` to `.proto.swift` when it hit version 2.0. This was probably an intentional change and you should update your code to match.

Comment: Thanks, and yes it was the only way